# League route, container, and PDO

Tags: php, dependency-injection, routes, containers

**TL;DR;**

How do I make a PDO connection available to the `CardOnFile\Controller` class so that it can make database queries? (I think I have to use the container, but not sure how).

**Background**

I want to avoid having multiple connections to the database each time I instantiate an object that needs database access. So, I *think* I need to instantiate ONE copy of a database connection (PDO) and then inject it into the classes where it will be needed using League\Route and League\Container.

I don't want to inject the container into the classes, because that's service location. But, I am completely unsure how to get the PDO object into the class that is going to need it so it can do work.

How to I make it so that the mapped callable has database access?

Code:

```
/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=foo;host=localhost';
$user = 'bar';
$password = 'supersecret';

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die(__FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__);
}

$container = new League\Container\Container;

$container->share('response', Zend\Diactoros\Response::class);
$container->share('request', function () {
    return Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals(
        $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_FILES
    );
});

$container->share('emitter', Zend\Diactoros\Response\SapiEmitter::class);

//DI PDO instance and connection.
$container->share('PDO', $pdo);

$route = new League\Route\RouteCollection($container);

$route->map('GET', '/cards/', 'CardOnFile\Controller::requestEmail' );
$route->map('GET', '/cards/emails/confirm', 'CardOnFile\Controller::getUserController' );
$route->map('GET', '/cards/emails/', 'CardOnFile\Controller::getCardController' );

$response = $route->dispatch($container->get('request'), $container->get('response'));

$container->get('emitter')->emit($response);
```

Comment: FWIW: [Design Patterns: How to create database object/connection only when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472924/design-patterns-how-to-create-database-object-connection-only-when-needed). Guess my typical approach is a singleton (with a factory/registry?). I think about how Doctrine is used in ZF and Symfony.

Comment: This is useful, and I agree with it, but I am not seeing how I can penetrate the scope of `$route->map()` to provide the database instance OR pass the `$pdo` variable to the class itself.

Comment: Edited to re-word the question to make what I need help with clearer.

Comment: Getting the connection in a **C**ontroller, I would probably just get the default connection from a static factory class. Not sure if your app had a concept of a 'controller helper' like some frameworks. `$db = $this->_helper->dbManager()`... Are you using a framework? Do you have some sort of database/model approach?

Comment: I am not using a framework. The approach you list here is valid, but I was trying to stay away from using the global namespace. Not sure I could unit test it this way.

Comment: I feel like the answer might be hidden in here, but I cannot find it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387343/dependency-injection-not-working-with-league-route-and-league-container

Comment: might be a good one to take to IRC... everyone will have an opinion. Good probably to talk through and rubber duck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176597/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-drdamnit).

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

The [docs](http://container.thephpleague.com/3.x/constructor-injection/) don't make this as obvious as they probably could, but the Container object requires that you have an interface defined AND that you use the `->add()->withArgument()` methods.

So, putting it all together, we have this:

**Instantiate your initial objects**

The code below, uses a closure in order to add a PDO object with the correct database connection to the container. This is the most performant way of adding objects to your container because they are not instantiated until used.

```
//DI PDO instance and connection.
$container->add('pdo', function() {
    /* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=foo;host=localhost';
    $user = 'bar';
    $password = 'supersecret';

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        die(__FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__);
    }

    return $pdo;
});
```

**Add your class to the container and specify the constructor***

```
$container
    ->add('controller', 'CardOnFile\Controller')
    ->withArgument($container->get('pdo'));
```

At this point, the Container object is going to try to use type hints to figure out if it should add something to the constructor, so make sure your class has a type hint in its contstructor. In this case, we are using the PDO class, but we're also in the namespace of CardOnFile, so we need to add the `use` statement as well as the type hint:

```
<?php

namespace CardOnFile;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
**use \PDO;**

class Controller implements CardControllerInterface
{
    public $content = '';
    protected $pdo = null;

    public function __construct(**PDO** $pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Create an interface so the Container can find / recognize that a PDO object should be injected into the instantiated object**

```
<?php

namespace CardOnFile;

interface CardControllerInterface
{

}
```

Yep. It's blank. It is just used to help out the Container system.

Now, you have successfully injected a PDO dependecy object into your app and its classes.